# How to save only non empty reducers' output in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, reduce, hdfs

In my application the reducer saves all the part files in HDFS but I want only the reducer will write the part files whose sizes are not 0bytes.Please let me know how to define it.

Comment: If you have 0 bytes output then what is the purpose of using a scalable system like Hadoop?

Comment: Some files are of non zero and some of them are of size zero.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible - see the documentation section on "Lazy Output":

http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Lazy+Output+Creation

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the old API, you can use the `NullOutputFormat` class:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NullOutputFormat;
conf.setOutputFormat(NullOutputFormat.class);
```